# SQL Server "." Alias Not Working

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, connection-string, alias

I've added an alias of "." which should point to my local (named) instance, ".\SQL2008". But when I try to connect to ".", it times out.

Am I missing something or is this not allowed?

[image: "." Alias Not Working]

[image: Timeout]

**Aliases I've tried which do not work:**

(Set for both 32 and 64-bit, I've also tried leaving the port blank.)

[image: Aliases which do not work.]

Comment: Have you tried giving it another more common name?

Comment: Yes, see updated screenshot.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the `connect to server dialog` with entries that work - i.e. without using an alias just specifying the instance name. I presume you have already tried connect to the instance before - is the server actually started?

Comment: @CSL, using `.\SQL2008', 'localhost\SQL2008`, etc. all work fine - I can connect to SQL Server (this is not a new installation). Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

If you are creating TCP/IP aliases you need to ensure the "SQL Server Browser" service is running. As well as checking the TCP/IP protocol is enabled for both server and client.

In **Sql Server configuration Manager** under the **SQL Server Services** node right click the **SQL Server Browser** and set the Start Mode to Automatic. 
If you are not going to do a reboot you will also need to Start the service manually.

The **SQL Server Browser** service is responsible for telling the client which port to use.
See [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Next time I run into this I'll give it a shot.

Comment: SQL Server Browser (Automatic -> then start it) and in my case no port was needed in settings.

Comment: If you've made changes in settings, it's wise to RESTART the SQL Server Browser as well. This solved all problems for me.

Answer (score 6):

It was not working for me after applied all the options mentioned here. For me,  port number to TCP/IP protocol was not assign.

[image]

After assigning (highlighted in yellow color) it started working for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is no limitation preventing that alias name. At leas it works on my machine ;)

However, when setting up the alias make sure you create it in the 32 as well as the 64 bit area:

[image]

I did also spell out `localhost` instead of just using the `.`:

[image]

Also, a SQL Server Alias always uses TCP/IP as connection protocol, which is not enabled by default. Under SQL Server Network Configuration (see above screen shot) check that TCP/IP is enabled for your instance.

Comment: Ah, I had TCP/IP enabled for client but not server. Both need to be enabled. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

In your Alias definition remove the `.\` from the Server box leaving just your instance name, that works on my machine. So in your case the dialog should look like this:

[image]

Comment: This is not working in general, at least not if there are multiple instances on the box.

Comment: Have you tried putting `Server\Instance name` in the Server box

Comment: I have multiple instances installed (SQL2012 too), and this isn't working. I've tried: `[MachineName]\SQL2008`, `localhost\SQL2008` and simply `SQL2008`. I've also tried using different aliases. Have a look at my latest screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to run "cliconfg" and setup the alias on your local machine as well.  If you have SSMS installed, create the alias in SQL Config Mgr, as this take precedance over the ones set in cliconfg.  Remember, SSMS uses 32bit connection to SQL Server, even if is 64bit.  If you don't set them locally, how does your PC know where to go for the alias.  You could create DNS entries as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue ,however on SQL server I did create alias on 32bit and 64 bit.I did the same thing on Sharepoint server using CliConfg.
In short, for 64 bits Windows operating systems run:
**C:\windows\syswow64\cliconfg.exe**
For 32 bits Windows operating systems run:
**C:\windows\system32\cliconfg.exe** 
on all server which you need to access to your database. Please see great article below.
https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-create-a-SQL-Alias-to-use-with-SharePoint.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure the selected protocol for alias (e.g. TCP/IP) is enabled under **SQL Server Network Configuration** / Protocols for *YOUR SERVER NAME*

This was the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I followed everything on this page and it still didn't work only to try change the server my alias was set up against. I changed it to '.' as the server name, so it gets the machines local instance and then everything worked, don't know why it didn't like putting the name of the sql server instance but anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, In my case, I remove port No. and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Mine worked after adding 32 bit Alias; run both 64 & 32 bit alias.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Despite my Client Protocol instances being set up on 64 bit SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration, it wasn't until I set up Aliases in SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit), that the alias was recognized in Object Explorer. I didn't need to add the alias to SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration at all.