# SQL Server Alias is not Working (Network Related Instance Error)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-connection

I have a database alias made using `SQL Server Configuration Manager`.

Here is what I done:

1. I've made an alias named "FCIS.SIS" for both 32-bit and 64 bit configurations with port number 1437.
2. TCP/IP enabled.
3. TCP/IP properties IPALL port 1437.
4. Both SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) and SQL Server Browser services have been restarted.

Here is what I get:
[image: Network related error]

I'm using SQL Server 2012 on windows 7

Also I've tried every single solution mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794151/sql-server-alias-not-working) but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to local server ?

Comment: As you are using different port number, are you specifying port number in your ssms connection?

Comment: @VenkataramanR yes sir I'm connecting to a local SQL server instance and I'm not using any port in my connection

Comment: @VenkataramanR it was working about a week ago and suddenly it doesn't now